# Upload multiple file to fire store with progress bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to upload more than one file to fire-store while showing a progress indicator. Am trying to achieve this by looping over the files chosen by the user. The files are picked using the flutter filePicker package.

```
for (var file in choosenFiles) {
     String fileName = file.name;
     String? filePath = file.path;

     File creatFile = File(filePath!);

     UploadTask task = FirebaseStorage.instance
     .ref('post_files/${value.id}-$fileName')
     .putData(creatFile.readAsBytesSync());

     task.snapshotEvents.listen((event) {
     setState(() {
       progress = ((event.bytesTransferred.toDouble() /
          event.totalBytes.toDouble() *
          100)
          .roundToDouble());
        });
       });
     }
```

for the progress indicator, i use a circularProgressIndicator to listen to the value of variable progress.

```
Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: progress / 100,
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              color: Colors.red,
              strokeWidth: 8,
            ),
          ),
        )
```

What could be the problem?. Will be grateful for any help. thanks.

Comment: What's the issue you're facing specifically? is it that when you're trying to upload the files, you're not seeing the progress indicator as one is uploading, then moving to the next one and so on? I can spot a few problems already. From the little code I see, you should be perform the action per file, but not in a loop, but rather using some sort of flag that indicates whether the current file is being uploaded and constantly checking if all are uploaded, and only when you're done listening on the snapshotEvents, is when you can either proceed to the next one or just stop performing uploads.

Comment: yes! the progress indicator does not show. And there is some other fatal issue that also occurs... when i try to add relatively big files, like of may be 6mbs, my app just crushes and exits debugging, Its so frustrating.